# sed with literal string--not input file

Tags: linux, unix, sed

This should be easy:  I want to run **sed** against a literal string, not an input file.  If you wonder why, it is to, for example edit values stored in variables, not necessarily text data.

When I do:

```bash
sed 's/,/','/g' "A,B,C"
```

where A,B,C is the literal which I want to change to A','B','C

I get

```
Can't open A,B,C
```

As though it thinks A,B,C is a file.

I tried piping it to echo:

```bash
echo "A,B,C" | sed 's/,/','/g'
```

I get a prompt.

What is the right way to do it?

Answer (score 186, accepted):

You have a single quotes conflict, so use:

```bash
echo "A,B,C" | sed "s/,/','/g"
```

If using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), you can do too (`<<<` is a `here-string`):

```bash
sed "s/,/','/g" <<< "A,B,C"
```

but not

```bash
sed "s/,/','/g"  "A,B,C"
```

because `sed` expect file(s) as argument(s)

**EDIT**:

if you use [ksh](/questions/tagged/ksh) or any other ones :

```bash
echo string | sed ...
```

Comment: strange, doesn't work for me... realizing it's some time ago this was posted, but strange deprecation if that's the problem

Answer (score 13):

Works like you want:

```
echo "A,B,C" | sed s/,/\',\'/g
```

Answer (score 10):

My version using variables in a bash script:

Find any backslashes and replace with forward slashes:

```bash
input="This has a backslash \\"

output=$(echo "$input" | sed 's,\\,/,g')

echo "$output"
```

Comment: this is useful when doing more complex commands, like `command input $(echo input | sed -e "s/x/y/;")`