# How to search and replace using grep

Tags: linux, shell, replace, grep

I need to recursively search for a specified string within all files and subdirectories within a directory and replace this string with another string.

I know that the command to find it might look like this:

```bash
grep 'string_to_find' -r ./*
```

But how can I replace every instance of `string_to_find` with another string?

Comment: I don't believe grep can do this (I could be wrong). Easier ways would be to use sed or perl to do the replacing

Comment: Try to use `sed -i 's/.*substring.*/replace/'`

Comment: @Eddy_Em That will replace the entire line with replace.  You need to use grouping to capture the part of the line before and after the substring and then put that in the replacement line. `sed -i 's/\(.*\)substring\(.*\)/\1replace\2/'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using grep and sed to find and replace a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178498/using-grep-and-sed-to-find-and-replace-a-string)

Comment: @see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171901/sed-command-find-and-replace-in-file-and-overwrite-file-doesnt-work-it-empties

Answer (score 314):

Another option is to use find and then pass it through sed.

```
find /path/to/files -type f -exec sed -i 's/oldstring/new string/g' {} \;
```

Comment: On OS X 10.10 Terminal, a proper extension string to parameter `-i` is required. For example, `find /path/to/files -type f -exec sed -i "" "s/oldstring/new string/g" {} \;` Anyway, providing empty string still creates a backup file unlike described in manual...

Comment: Why do I get "sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence". And yes, I added the `-i ""` for OS X. It works otherwise.

Comment: I had the illegal byte sequence issue on macOS 10.12, and this question/answer solved my issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19242275/re-error-illegal-byte-sequence-on-mac-os-x.

Comment: This touches every file so file times are modified; and converts line endings from `CRLF` to `LF` on Windows.

Comment: My old and new strings have / because they are paths... this won't work.

Comment: Could you not escape the forward slash(/) with a back slash (\)? Please paste  what you are searching for and I can send you the query.

Answer (score 257):

I got the answer.

```
grep -rl matchstring somedir/ | xargs sed -i 's/string1/string2/g'
```

Comment: This would scan through the matching files twice... once with `grep` and then again with `sed`.  Using `find` method is more efficient but this method you mention does work.

Comment: On OS X you will need to change `sed -i 's/str1/str2/g'` to `sed -i "" 's/str1/str2/g'` for this to work.

Comment: @cmevoli with this method, `grep` goes through all the files and `sed` only scans the files matched by `grep`. With the `find` method in the other answer, `find` first lists all files, and then `sed` will scan through all the files in that directory. So this method is not necessarily slower, it depends on how many matches there are and the differences in search speeds between `sed`, `grep` and `find`.

Comment: OTOH this way lets you PREVIEW what grep finds BEFORE actually replacing, reducing the risk of failure greatly, especially for regex n00bs like myself

Comment: This is also useful when your grep replacement is more clever than sed. For example ripgrep obeys .gitignore while sed doesn't.

Comment: What does the `1` after `-r` do? Recursive depth?

Comment: @Yankee it's lower-case L, and it means "Suppress normal output; instead print the  name  of  each  input file  from  which  output would normally have been printed.  The scanning will stop on the first  match.   (-l  is  specified  by POSIX." http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/grep1.html

Comment: For this reason, it might be a good idea to pass the grep output as a literal string to sed. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13055889/sed-with-literal-string-not-input-file#13055913

Comment: to make the whole thing case-insensitive add `i` flags on both `grep` and `sed`: `grep -ril matchstring somedir/ | xargs sed -i 's/string1/string2/i'`

Answer (score 73):

You could even do it like this:

**Example**

```
grep -rl 'windows' ./ | xargs sed -i 's/windows/linux/g'
```

This will search for the string '**windows**' in all files relative to the current directory and replace '**windows**' with '**linux**' for each occurrence of the string in each file.

Comment: The `grep` is only useful if there are files which should not be modified. Running `sed` on all files will update the file's modification date but leave the contents unchanged if there are no matches.

Comment: @tripleee: Be careful with *... but [sed] leave the contents unchanged if there are no matches"*. When using `-i`, I believe `sed` changes the file time of every file it touches, even though the contents are unchanged. `sed` also converts line endings. I don't use `sed` on Windows in a Git repo because all `CRLF` are changed to `LF`.

Comment: This command needs a "" after the -i to denote that no backup files will be made after the in-place substitution takes place, at least in macosx. Check the man page for details. If you want a backup, this is where you put the extension of the file to be created.

Comment: For spaces is file names you need to do NULL termination on grep and xargs.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17296525/grep-and-sed-with-spaces-in-filenames

Comment: I love the funny subtle subliminal command to replace Windows with Linux

Answer (score 43):

This works best for me on OS X:

```
grep -r -l 'searchtext' . | sort | uniq | xargs perl -e "s/matchtext/replacetext/" -pi
```

Source: http://www.praj.com.au/post/23691181208/grep-replace-text-string-in-files

Comment: this is perfect! also works with ag: `ag "search"  -l -r .   | sort | uniq | xargs perl -e 's/search/replace' -pi`

Comment: @sebastiankeller Your Perl command lacks the final slash, which is a syntax error.

Comment: Why is the `sort -u` even part of this? In what circumstances would you expect `grep -rl` to produce the same file name twice?

Comment: This is a great answer for OS X

Answer (score 8):

Usually not with grep, but rather with `sed -i 's/string_to_find/another_string/g'` or `perl -i.bak -pe 's/string_to_find/another_string/g'`.

Comment: I think this is probably the easiest method on here to get the job done. Forcing grep when it is not needed is unnecessary.

Answer (score 6):

Other solutions mix regex syntaxes. To use perl/PCRE patterns for **both** search and replace, and process only matching files, this works quite well:

```sh
grep -rlIZPi 'match1' | xargs -0r perl -pi -e 's/match2/replace/gi;'
```

`match1` and `match2` are usually identical but `match2` can contain more advanced features that are only relevant to the substitution, e.g. capturing groups.

Translation: `grep` recursively and list matching filenames, each separated by null to protect any special characters; pipe any filenames to `xargs` which is expecting a null-separated list; if any filenames are received, pass them to `perl` to perform the actual substitutions.

For *case-sensitive* matching, drop the `i` flag from `grep` and the `i` pattern modifier from the `s///` expression, but **not** the `i` flag from `perl` itself. To include binary files, remove the `I` flag from `grep`.

Comment: Perl itself is quite capable of recursing a file structure.  In fact, there is a tool [`find2perl`](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.8.8/find2perl.html) which ships with Perl which does this sort of thing without any `xargs` trickery.

Comment: @tripleee `find` doesn't search file contents, and the point is to only process matching files without writing a Perl program.

Comment: This is a nice solution for Windows, as it avoids the sed-based solutions' issue of converting the line endings.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Be very careful when using `find` and `sed` in a git repo! If you don't exclude the binary files you can end up with this error:

```
error: bad index file sha1 signature 
fatal: index file corrupt
```

To solve this error you need to revert the `sed` by replacing your `new_string` with your `old_string`. This will revert your replaced strings, so you will be back to the beginning of the problem.

The correct way to search for a string and replace it is to skip `find` and use `grep` instead in order to ignore the binary files:

```
sed -ri -e "s/old_string/new_string/g" $(grep -Elr --binary-files=without-match "old_string" "/files_dir")
```

Credits for @hobs

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I would do:

```
find /path/to/dir -type f -iname "*filename*" -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i '/searchstring/s/old/new/g'
```

this will look for all files containing `filename` in the file's name under the `/path/to/dir`, than for every file found, search for the line with `searchstring` and replace `old` with `new`.

Though if you want to omit looking for a specific file with a `filename` string in the file's name, than simply do:

```
find /path/to/dir -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i '/searchstring/s/old/new/g'
```

This will do the same thing above, but to all files found under `/path/to/dir`.

Answer (score 0):

Modern rust tools can be used to do this job.
For example to replace in all (non ignored) files "oldstring" and "oldString" with "newstring" and "newString" respectively you can :

### Use [fd](https://github.com/sharkdp/fd) and [sd](https://github.com/chmln/sd)

```sh
fd -tf -x sd 'old([Ss]tring)' 'new$1' {}
```

### Use [ned](https://github.com/nevdelap/ned)

```sh
ned -R -p 'old([Ss]tring)' -r 'new$1' .
```

### Use [ruplacer](https://github.com/dmerejkowsky/ruplacer)

```sh
ruplacer --go 'old([Ss]tring)' 'new$1' .
```

### Ignored files

To include ignored (by `.gitignore`) and hidden files you have to specify it :

- use `-IH` for `fd`,
- use `--ignored --hidden`for `ruplacer`.

Answer (score -1):

Another option would be to just use perl with globstar.

Enabling `shopt -s globstar` in your `.bashrc` (or wherever) allows the `**` glob pattern to match all sub-directories and files recursively.

Thus using `perl -pXe 's/SEARCH/REPLACE/g' -i **` will recursively
replace `SEARCH` with `REPLACE`.

The `-X` flag tells perl to "disable all warnings" - which means that
it won't complain about directories.

The globstar also allows you to do things like `sed -i 's/SEARCH/REPLACE/g' **/*.ext` if you wanted to replace `SEARCH` with `REPLACE` in all child files with the extension `.ext`.

Comment: *"Another option would be to just use perl with globstar..."* - Not on Posixy machines, like Solaris. That's why I am specifically looking for `grep` and `sed`.