# grep and sed with spaces in filenames

Tags: linux, search, replace, sed, grep

Currently, I have

```
grep -irl $schema $WORKDIR/ | xargs sed -i 's/'"$schema"'/EXI1/gI'
```

which doesn't work for filenames with spaces.

Any ideas, how to search and replace recursively for all files?

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Add the `-Z` (aka `--null`) flag to `grep`, and the `-0` (also aka `--null`) flag to `xargs`.
This will output NUL terminated file names, and tell `xargs` to read NUL terminated arguments.

eg.

```
grep -irlZ $schema $WORKDIR/ | xargs -0 sed -i 's/'"$schema"'/EXI1/gI'
```

Comment: There should be an option to upvote twice.

Answer (score 3):

find with sed should work:

```
find $WORKDIR/ -type f -exec sed -i.bak "s/$schema/EXI1/gI" '{}' +
```

OR

```
find $WORKDIR/ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i.bak "s/$schema/EXI1/gI"
```

Comment: This solution is better because it doesn't search each file twice (once with grep, once with sed). This should be chosen over the other.

Comment: Above commands doesn't search the content of the file like grep all it does is find all the files in the WORKDIR. My command uses grep to find the files that contains the $schema and passes the files to sed to do the replace, this way only the files that contain the $schema are touched. whereas with find all files are touched

Comment: You don't really need to search using grep since using sed you're anyway doing search & replacement.