# Duplicate PHP Tags removal

Tags: replace, sed, duplicates

Someone decided to remove an injection script but forgot to remove the additional php tags so now thousands of php files have the following;

`head content-none.php
<?php
<?php
/**`

Need to find all files with lines 1 and 2 being the above and remove the duplicate.  Any help?
I have this;

`sed -i -e '1 <?php/g' -e '2,$ s/` but its incomplete and I'm clueless now :(

Comment: Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15402770/how-to-grep-and-replace

Comment: I've actually read over that first but that didnt work.  Its just 2 php tags and thousands of files have them.

Comment: check: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLcUid3OP_4OW-rwv_mBHzx9MmE5TxvvcQ

Comment: `for i in find . -name "*.php"; sed -i -e 'N;s/<?php\n<?php/<?php/'; end` or similar.