# Manipulating a text file with grep

Tags: linux, grep

Ok, so I have a text file formatted like this, it has several rows going down.

```
EXAMPLE1:EXAMPLE2:EXAMPLE3
EXAMPLE1:EXAMPLE2:EXAMPLE3
EXAMPLE1:EXAMPLE2:EXAMPLE3
```

I want to use grep to change it to look like this

```
EXAMPLE2:EXAMPLE3
```

Basically I want to take out the first part before the :

If someone could please tell me how to do this it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to grep and replace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15402770/how-to-grep-and-replace)

Comment: Do you want to take out all first fields or only when it contains `EXAMPLE1` at the start of the line. In that case you can use something like `sed 's/^EXAMPLE1://' textfile`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `cut` utility to filter out columns given a delimiter.

In this example, the delimiter is `:` and you want every column starting with the second:

```
$ cut -d: -f2- < input.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `-o` flag to select the part of the input which matches a regex in `grep`.

**Example**

```
$ grep -o "[^:]*:[^:]*$" input
EXAMPLE2:EXAMPLE3
EXAMPLE2:EXAMPLE3
EXAMPLE2:EXAMPLE3
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this. Hope this helps.

```
awk -F":" '{printf "%s:%s\n" ,$1,$2}' file.txt
```

Output

```
EXAMPLE1:EXAMPLE2
EXAMPLE1:EXAMPLE2
EXAMPLE1:EXAMPLE2
```

Answer (score -1):

Here it is:

```
cut -d':' -f2,3 filename
```

Output:

```
EXAMPLE2:EXAMPLE3
EXAMPLE2:EXAMPLE3
EXAMPLE2:EXAMPLE3
```

Comment: How is this different from the answer given by Bo Borgerson 4 hours ago?