# Delete file containing opening php tag and empty lines

Tags: php, regex, linux, bash

I'm working with a legacy PHP project that I inherited that had over a thousand files with nothing but includes to other classes. Now that I've refactored it to use composer, and used PHPstorm to remove the references to including the classes, I have over 1200 files with nothing but an opening php tag and a few empty lines.

I was able to use this regex to find them: `\<\?php\n^(\s*$){1,}\z`

However, when I try to replace that with nothing, or with a string like `DELETEME` PhpStorm won't actually do the replace.

Is there a way via the command line that I can recursively search for files that contain only an opening PHP tag and empty lines and then delete those files?

Comment: Still not sure if you want to delete the files, or just replace the tags. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15402972/7544655) answer from rezizter should help you.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, I want to delete the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a not so well known pattern: `\Q...\E`. This leaves everything in between as it is, so you don't need to escape any special characters:

```
\A        # the very start of the string
\Q<?php\E # <?php
\s+       # whitespaces including newlines, at least once
\Q?>\E    # ?>
\Z        # the very end of the string
```

---

In `PHP` with the help of **[`glob()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)** this would be:

```
<?php
$regex = '~\A\Q<?php\E\s+\Q?>\E\Z~';

foreach (glob("*.php") as $file) {
    $content = file_get_contents($file);
    if (preg_match($regex, $content)) {
        // do sth. here
        // e.g. delete the file
    }
}
?>
```

See a demo of the [**regex on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/aKzWwt/1).

Comment: Thanks Jan, that was exactly what I needed. I used the RecursiveDirectoryIterator instead of glob and I modified slightly since my files did not have closing tags. I put the solution here in case anyone else ever needs this. https://gist.github.com/rorymcdaniel/8d359ffe457de1dd7765bb7669446ba7