# How can I grep/sed taking find/replace pairs from a file?

Tags: regex, sed, grep

I want to run a find and replace using a series of value pairs taken from a file (or two files, if that makes the task any easier). The find and replace strings are literal ones, not regexes in the practical sense. At the moment the file is tab-delimited, `findstring \t replacestring`, one pair per line, but I can change that as required.

I know a little about regex but with Unix commands I really need clear "copy and paste" instructions. Earlier in this project I was pleased to discover `grep -f` to get find strings from a file, but it seems that [grep can't do the same thing for the replace strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15402770/how-to-grep-and-replace).

Can I do this with a mixture of grep, sed and so on? The thread above explains how to pipe grep to sed, but then I need to tell sed how to read replace strings from the file.

I'm on macOS (with homebrew) if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a file with a list of `sed` commands like this in a file called `commands.sed`:

```
s|cat|cats|g
s|dog|dogs|g
s|person|people|g
```

and run it on some input with:

```
echo "House mouse cat dog person dog person" | sed -f commands.sed
```

and it will replace `cat` with `cats`, `dog` with `dogs` and `person` with `people` producing:

```
House mouse cats dogs people dogs people
```

So we want to turn your file with substitutions into a command file like that - using `sed`! So, if your replacements file `subs.txt` contains lines like this with the two words on each line separated by a TAB:

```
cat cats
dog dogs
person  people
```

That would be:

```
sed -e 's/^/s|/' -e $'s/\t/|/' -e 's/$/|g/' subs.txt > commands.sed
```

and then you can apply it with:

```
sed -f commands.sed SomeFile
```

---

Rather than creating a file with the commands in, we can run a `process substitution` like this to dynamically generate them, and do it all in one go with:

```
echo "House mouse cat dog person dog person" | sed -f <(sed -e 's/^/s|/' -e $'s/\t/|/' -e 's/$/|g/' subs.txt)
```

Comment: @CharlesButcher :. this is a good solution, but note what happens once your substitute `dogs` for `dog`. Now `dog` will match `dogs` and if you run the script again, you'll wind up with `dogss` ;-) The moral being, always work on copies of your data. If you discover a mistake, rerunning a  program can compound the problem ;-! Good luck to all.

Comment: Note that if you have tens of thousands of files to process, you can generate the command file just once and apply it to all files in parallel with **GNU Parallel** - just ask.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thank you so much for such a careful, patient and accurate walkthrough. It worked first try – well, second, but that was because my `subs.txt` had an unwanted space before the tab. A great result, and I've learned a lot for the future.

Comment: @shellter A good point, thank you! I have messed up so many times with search-and-replace in word processors that I've learned to be careful…