# How to batch remove entire <sup>text here</sup> from an html document

Tags: html

How to batch remove entire string of superscript `<sup>text here</sup>` from an html document. The `<sup>` tags are being used for foot notes and there are over 900,  but I want to delete them altogether from the document.

I use Linux and Windows so which ever works for getting this done.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15402770/how-to-grep-and-replace

Comment: In your editor `ctrl+h` is usually replace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I could not get sed to edit the html file, but here is how I did it.

I used xed text editor and used the "Find and Replace" tool with this code: `<sup.*</sup>` just be sure that the .* button is on on the left side. It found all instances of the superscript tags and just replaced with empty space.

Answer (score 0):

On linux, you can use the `sed` command with the `-i` flag (in-place edit)

```sh
sed -i 's/<sup>\w+<\/sup>//' /path/to/filename.html
```

Comment: I just tried it no errors but it did not remove them. here is a sample of what I want to remove: <span><sup class="calibre14"><a href="#calibre_link-706" id="calibre_link-924" class="calibre2">1</a></sup></span></p>

Comment: I looked up the man pages for sed, and I tried this:(( sed -i 's/<sup>.*</sup>//' index.html )) but I get this error: sed: -e expression #1, char 17: unknown option to `s'