# How can I remove a newline (\n) at the end of a string?

Tags: string, bash, replace

### The problem

I have multiple property lines in a single string separated by `\n` like this:

```
LINES2="Abc1.def=$SOME_VAR\nAbc2.def=SOMETHING_ELSE\n"$LINES
```

The `LINES` variable

- might contain an undefined set of characters
- may be empty. If it is empty, I want to avoid the trailing `\n`.

I am open for any command line utility (sed, tr, awk, ... you name it).

### Tryings

I tried this to no avail

```
sed -z 's/\\n$//g' <<< $LINES2
```

I also had no luck with **tr**, since it does not accept regex.

### Idea

There might be an approach to convert the `\n` to something else. But since `$LINES` can contain arbitrary characters, this might be dangerous.

### Sources

I skim read through the following questions

- [How can I replace a newline (\n) using sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n-using-sed)
- [sed with literal string--not input file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13055889/sed-with-literal-string-not-input-file)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19345906/3163306

Comment: @avrilalejandro `tr` removes all occurences of the search term. I only want to remove the last occurence.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one solution:

```
LINES2="Abc1.def=$SOME_VAR"$'\n'"Abc2.def=SOMETHING_ELSE${LINES:+$'\n'$LINES}"
```

The syntax `${name:+value}` means "insert `value` if the variable `name` exists and is not empty." So in this case, it inserts a newline followed by `$LINES` if `$LINES` is not empty, which seems to be precisely what you want.

I use `$'\n'` because `"\n"` is not a newline character. A more readable solution would be to define a shell variable whose value is a single newline.

It is not necessary to quote strings in shell assignment statements, since the right-hand side of an assignment does not undergo word-splitting nor glob expansion. Not quoting would make it easier to interpolate a `$'\n'`.

It is not usually advisable to use UPPER-CASE for shell variables because the shell and the OS use upper-case names for their own purposes. Your local variables should normally be lower case names.

So if I were not basing the answer on the command in the question, I would have written:

```
lines2=Abc1.def=$someVar$'\n'Abc2.def=SOMETHING_ELSE${lines:+$'\n'$lines}
```

Comment: `It is not necessary to quote strings in shell assignment statements`, why have you quoted the entire thing then?

Comment: @123: I was copying the line in the OP.

Comment: What do you mean, that line is literally the entire answer, you changed some of it, so why leave the quotes?

Comment: @123: It's a possibly bad habit: Make the minimal necessary changes so as to focus on the part which is actually the answer.

Comment: Fair enough, just thought it may be a bit confusing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll check it out on monday.