# Using sed command in variable

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have the following variable TABLES with multiple lines

```
TABLES="foobar
test
bar
foo
"
```

I have a variable SKIP with this `sed` command

```
$ echo $SKIP
/bar/d;/foo/d;
```

I want to use it on sed, like this

```
echo $TABLES | sed "$SKIP"
```

But this returns nothing! If I replace the variable with the current content it works

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: sed "$SKIP" <<< "$TABLES"

Comment: You just needed to quote your shell variables so `echo "$TABLES" | sed "$SKIP"` would have worked as well

Comment: sed "$SKIP" <<< "$TABLES" did the trick

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sed with literal string--not input file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13055889/sed-with-literal-string-not-input-file)

Answer (score -3):

> What I am doing wrong?

You are not quoting variable expansion. Unquoted variable expansion undergo word splitting, which splits the result of expansion also on newlines, changing it into words. You are doing:

```
echo foobar test bar foo | ...
```

Because `echo` joins the arguments with space, this is effectively one line. `/bar/d` removes that line.

Quote variable expansion to prevent word splitting. Check your scripts with shellcheck.

```
echo "$TABLES" | sed "$SKIP"
```